# Tool/Package to convert jQuery code to Javascript equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there some tool or package that can convert jQuery code into its vanilla JavaScript equivalent. I have built a webpage using jQuery but now I want to transition towards plain JavaScript to improve loading time, I could do it manually but it would take a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is vanilla javascript. Object oriented code that helps you build applications faster. From your question I can understand that there is not mutch jq there. If you are considering page load and jquery first you should check different suspects: code quality. Rewriting bad jq code into bad js code will not change the page load

Comment: I was using jQuery on one of my other react app for just a few minor animations, I decided to use vanilla Javascript instead and changed the code manually, it reduced the size of the build file from 120KB to 90KB but this webpage uses quite a lot of functions, I could do it manually aswell but it would be better if I could find a tool for the same.